# Moving a menu to a new div element

Tags: html, css

I have a menu on my website which is situated like this,

```
header>.container>nav{
border:none;
position: absolute;
top:50px;
right: 30px;
text-align: left
}
```

What I am trying to do is relocate nav inside of a new element within the structure called topLine, and so my new code is,

```
header.container.clearfix.topLine.nav{
border:none;
position: absolute;
top:50px;
right: 30px;
text-align: left;
background-color:#282b30;
```

}

However it is not working and I am not sure what I am missing.

The HTML code is below

```
 <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topLine">
        <!--MENU-->
        <nav class="clearfix">
            <a href="" id="header-menu-button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>  
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is `topLine` in your HTML?

Comment: The basic problem is that you're missing all the `>` characters in your selector.

Comment: Can they not be replaced by using .

Comment: No. `x.y` matches an `x` that has class `y`. `x > .y` matches an element with class `y` that is a child of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

i would have posted a comment but i don't have enough xp yet. :)
some periods that you have in your css should't be there. Periods are for referencing a class.  for example, i see a `.nav` but you don't have a `class="nav"` anywhere in the html. if you want to refer to a child element, use `>`. 
So instead, do `header > .container > .clearfix > .topLine > nav {`